# as.Date() does not respect POSIXct time zones

Tags: r, date, datetime, posixct

Okay so here is a subtle "quirk" in the r as.Date function converting from a POSIXct with a timezone, which I am wondering if it is a bug.

```
> as.POSIXct("2013-03-29", tz = "Europe/London")
[1] "2013-03-29 GMT"
> as.Date(as.POSIXct("2013-03-29", tz = "Europe/London"))
[1] "2013-03-29"
```

So far no problem, but.....

```
> as.POSIXct("2013-04-01", tz = "Europe/London")
[1] "2013-04-01 BST"
> as.Date(as.POSIXct("2013-04-01", tz = "Europe/London"))
[1] "2013-03-31"
```

Anybody seen this? Is this a bug or another quirk? April fools?

Comment: `Europe/Berlin` *doesn't* as well with `as.Date` goes back to March 31st.

Comment: I'm running this on Windows 7 x64. Let me try on Ubuntu....

Comment: But this happens with `"2013-03-01"` as well. `as.Date` gives Feb 28th.

Comment: so... we have a problem? Because I'm getting the same issue on OS/X. Both R2.15.2. Have come across other issues like this before with xts but this time xts is not loaded.

Comment: This isn't a subtle quirk. It's a serious issue IMO

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default time zone for `as.Date.POSIXct` is `"UTC"` (see the help page). Try `as.Date(as.POSIXct("2013-04-01", tz = "Europe/London"),tz = "Europe/London")`.

Comment: aha! Guess I should have woken up later ;)